# Spring - How to display submenu in all URLs

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i'm using spring boot + thymeleaf, i devided all fragment as header, footer, ...

**this is my header**

```html
<div th:fragment="header" th:remove="tag">
 <!--header-->
 <div class="logo">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="logo-info">
    <a href="index.html">
     <h1>Logo</h1> 
     <!-- <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-grain" aria-hidden="true"></span> -->
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--//header-->
 <!--navigation-->
 <div class="top-nav">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">Menu</button>
   </div>
   <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle hvr-bounce-to-bottom" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Gallery<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" th:each="category: ${listCategory}">
       <li><a class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom" th:href="@{/category/${category.getId()} } " th:text="${category.getName()}"></a></li>
      </ul></li>
     <li class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom"><a href="codes.html">Short Codes</a></li>
     <li class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom"><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </div>
 <!--//navigation-->
</div>
```

**This is picture**
[this is picture for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAM0S.png)

i want to display data from mysql to 'Gallery' menu (Gallery1, Gallery2, Gallery3) 
so when i go to my website, all URLs will show submenu in 'Gallery'

**UPDATE: this is controller**

```html
@Controller
public class CategoryController {
 @Autowired
 private CategoryService categoryService;

 @RequestMapping(value = "/category/{id}")
 public String getCategoryByID(Model model, @PathVariable(name = "id") Long id) {
  List<CategoryDTO> categoryDTOs = categoryService.getAllCategory();
  model.addAttribute("listCategory", categoryDTOs);
  return "common/header";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Spring and Thymeleaf also, but try to do an Repository

```
     public interface CategoryRepository extends 
           JpaRepository<CategoryDTO, String>{
     }
```

Controller:

```
      @Controller
      public class CategoryController {

@Autowired
private categoryRepository categoryRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/category")
public String getCategoryByID(Model model) {
    List<CategoryDTO> categoryDTOs = 
            categoryRepository.findAll();

    model.addAttribute("listCategory", categoryDTOs);
    return "common/header";
}
 }
```

And in Thymeleaf try to do something like this:

```
       category: ${listCategory}"  th:value=" ${file.fileName}"
       <li><a class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom" 
        th:value="${category.getName()}"></a></li>
```

Comment: its also get all category.
but in controller, its only work when call /category
i mean when i go to any url, it'll display category in header
header is common